# Display a warning if about to destroy a view with unsaved data

Tags: events, view, model, backbone.js

I want to display a warning to the user when an action they take will cause the loss of unsaved changes if the view is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I always thought thought that it would be useful for the Model to have a `synced` flag.  One that gets cleared when you set anything (and by default when creating a new object) but gets set on `save`.  You would have to extend `Backbone.Model` or create a new base class to use with your models to make it happen, but it would give you the ability to ask your models: "Are you synced with the server?"